# What difference between .php and abc.blade.php when i give file names in laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel

What difference between .php and abc.blade.php when i give file names
in laravel 5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Files ending in `.blade.php` will allow you to use the [Blade templating language](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade) while "normal" `.php` files won't. Note that you can use PHP code in both files with the usual `<?php ... ?>`